# Existence of two sequences

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

Does there exists two nonnegative sequences

$\{a_{n, m} \} $ and $\{r_m\} $
such that

(1). $a_{n, m}\in (\frac{1}{N_o},1)$ for some integer $N_o$ for all $n, m$

(2). $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a^2_{n, m}=r_m$

and

$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}r_{ m} $ converges.

If yes, can we find a family of such sequences?

Comment: Here are some useful links that, being a newcomer here, you should definitely check [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Thank you for the hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a^2_{n, m}$ converges, $a_{n,m}\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ and thus it cannot be bounded from below.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I forgot that! So the only choice to have $a_{n, m} \in(0,1)$

Comment: yes exactly! you can't be "too far" away from $0$ with the summability condition